# X11 touch the value of the shivers . Is there any way?

Tags: x11, input, touch-screen

I am using the X- widnwos.
I use the touch screen.
If you are a touch on the touch-screen cursor is unstable.

Below is the video.

**https://youtu.be/jMub9-T_wEA**

How do I improve the following phenomena?

Below is a version of the package that I use ( I'm used to cross-compile all X.)

xorg-server : **xorg-server-1.17.3**

x-input-driver : **xf86-input-evdev-2.10.0**

Below are the details of my settings.(/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf)

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "calibration"
        MatchProduct    "my Touchscreen"
        Option  "Calibration"   "166 3939 186 3814"
        Option  "SwapAxes"      "1"
        Option  "InvertX"   "on"
        Option  "InvertY"   "on"
EndSection
```